# Flutter: how to use plataform channels to navigate to another iOS ViewController?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am not an iOS developer, so I have no idea how to implement such thing.

I've this working properly on Android using platform channels and starting a new activity. But how to make this on IOS?

How to make the NavigationController work with Flutter? Should I embed the FlutterViewController into a NavigationController? But what happens to the navigation bar? Can I hide it and show it only when I want?

Please, someone help.

Comment: What do you really want to do, please tell me the user case.

Comment: My app needs RTSP camera streaming. But flutter vídeo plug-in does not support it. So I will make native implementations of streaming on Android and IOS. Then, I will open those native separated screens to perform a full screen streaming. After the streaming is done, I will back to the Flutter's app side.

Comment: Now that makes it clear. I am sorry because I am also from Android side.

Answer (score 0):

it is a ios problem, just create a new viewController to show video,

and navigate from FlutterViewController  to it

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
NSLog(@"=========finishLaunch");

FlutterViewController *flutterViewController = (FlutterViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

self.naviController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:flutterViewController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.naviController;
[self.naviController setNavigationBarHidden:true];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];}
```

> //this is methodchannel handle

```
[flutterChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall* call, FlutterResult result) {    
  }else if([@"playM3U8Video" isEqualToString:call.method]){
        NSString* videoUrl = call.arguments[@"_vUrl"];
        NSString* _vName = call.arguments[@"_vName"];
        VideoViewController *videoVC = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];
        videoVC.vUrl = videoUrl;
        videoVC.vName = _vName;
        videoVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"返回" style:0 target:self action:@selector(back)];

        [self.naviController setNavigationBarHidden:false];
        [self.naviController pushViewController:videoVC animated:false ];
    }
```